# Remove radio buttons if they are not checked

Tags: javascript, radio-button

Anyone know how to loop through a group of radio buttons and remove ones that haven't been checked?

What I'm trying to do is set up a quiz to where once you've submitted the quiz it will only show you the answers to the radio buttons you selected...

Any help would be great appreciated!

Page I'm working on: http://adventures.org/quiz/default_post.asp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is pure javascript, you would use something like:

```
var inputs = document.getElementById('myForm').getElementsByTagName('input'), 
    i = inputs.length - 1; //Loop backwards to avoid issues when removing an input 
    for(; i >= 0; i--) { //for loop
    //Is this an unchecked radio button
    if(inputs[i].type === 'radio' && !inputs[i].checked) {
        //Remove this input element
        inputs[i].parentNode.removeChild(inputs[i]);
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**

Per user's comment, it would appear that he is trying to remove the entire `label` element that contains the `radio` input.  The below code will accomplish this.

```
var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName('input'), 
    i = inputs.length - 1, 
    item;
//Loop backwards through items
for(; i >= 0; i--) {
    //If this is an unchecked radio button
    if(inputs[i].type === 'radio' && !inputs[i].checked) {
        //Begin trying to find the label item
        item = inputs[i].parentNode;
        //Is this the label item
        while(item && item.nodeName.toLowerCase() !== 'label') {
            item = item.parentNode;
        }
        //If an item was found
        if(item && item.parentNode) {
            //Remove the label element
            item.parentNode.removeChild(item);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: doesn't seem to work. Here is the link to the page I am working on. http://adventures.org/quiz/default_post.asp

Comment: @justincron I just ran that exact code on your page, and it does indeed remove the radio buttons as you described in your post.  Are you looking to remove the entire answer as well?

Comment: Yes I would like to remove the radio button and answer connected with it.

Comment: Worked like a charm Kyle!! Thanks a TON!

Answer (score 0):

You could do this:

```js
var yourForm = document.getElementById("yourFormId");
var removeUnchecked = function (form) {
  var childrenList = form.children,
      num = childrenList.length - 1;
  for (var i = 0; i >= num; i--) {
    if (!childrenList[i].checked) {
      form.removeChild(childrenList[i]);
    }
  }
}

removeUnchecked(yourForm);
```

Replace the `id` in the first line with the `id` of your form element.

Comment: doesn't seem to work. Here is the link to the page I am working on. http://adventures.org/quiz/default_post.asp

Comment: I will revise it now (I couldn't when I posted it) and update my answer.